# F# SqlDataConnection TypeProvider not working with Sql Server Ce

Tags: f#, sql-server-ce, type-providers

I'am playing around with the new F# type providers in VS 11 Beta in Win 8 CP and I can't convince the SqlDataConenction type provider to work with a SqlCe database. The code:

```
open System
open System.Data
open System.Data.Linq
open System.Data.SqlServerCe
open Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders
open Microsoft.FSharp.Linq

type dbSchema = SqlDataConnection<"Data Source=C:\Test\Test.sdf">
```

The database exists and was created using the VS11 dialog Server Explorer/Data Connections/Add New Connection/Sql Server CE/Create. No matter what I try I always get the following error:

> The type provider
>   'Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.DesignTime.DataProviders'
>   reported an error: Error reading schema. Error : Cannot open
>   'C:\Test\Test.sdf'. Provider 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5' not
>   installed.

What I've tried so far:

- installed the Sql Server Ce 3.5, but the error is still the same.
- modified the connection string & added a matching reference to the project:

  - "Provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5;Data Source=C:\Test\Test.sdf"
  - "Provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0;Data Source=C:\Test\Test.sdf"

Comment: Is it any different if you try `"Data Source=C:\\Test\\Test.sdf"`?

Comment: According to this example on MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361033(v=vs.110).aspx#BKMK_SetUpTypeProv) the escaping seems correct, they too don't escape the backslash

Comment: In F#, you only need to escape backslash if the non-escaped version means something. "\I" in the sample does not mean anything, but "\t" in your code means the Tab. However, I don't think the provider works with CE - I couldn't get it to work last time I tried.

Comment: @TomasPetricek - the provider may not work with CE, but I believe it could since LINQ to SQL does support CE 3.5: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546181.aspx

Comment: From what I can tell, it doesn't seem to work with CE. I asked the same question a few days ago, and got an answer which I think meant that it doesn't work, but he hasn't answered my request for clarification. Can see that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10154849/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-compact-edition-4-0-with-a-type-provider-in-f

Answer (score 1):

I know this question was asked few years ago, but for future ref:

```
[<Literal>]
let connection_string =@"Data Source=C:\Test\Test.sdf"

type dbSchema = SqlDataConnection<connection_string>
```